# Expand Very Large Data Set

Tags: stata, expand

How do you perform expansion of very large data sets in Stata without the use of `expand`? In SAS, by using some codes (which I don't know of), you can preserve the actual size of your data set (without making it explode) but still treat it as if you expanded it.

My current sales data contains 12M+ observations. One of the variables, units sold, can have a value anywhere from 1 to 1000. I need to get a picture of the unit price distribution for all available brands. I figured out that I need to perform expansion in order to capture true price distribution on a graph based on selling frequency.

```
brand  units_sold    price_per_unit
A       11          15.9876
B       3           17.22727
C       8           15.86364
D       8           17.22727
E       2           17.22727
F       3           17.22727
G       1           17.22727
H       8           18.13636
I       3           18.13636
G       4           17.22727
```

Comment: I think you mean _weights_. See `help weights`.

Comment: This might be considered off-topic by some users here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use frequency weights that indicate the number of "duplicated" price observations:

```
clear

// Fake Data
input str1 brand int units_sold double price_per_unit
    A       11          15.9876
    B       3           17.22727
    C       8           15.86364
    D       8           17.22727
    E       2           17.22727
    F       3           17.22727
    G       1           17.22727
    H       8           18.13636
    I       3           18.13636
    G       4           17.22727
end

// Histogram and summarize with weights
tw hist price_per_unit [fweight=units_sold], frac
sum price_per_unit [fweight=units_sold], detail
```